# Is there any method to generate the minimum number of intersecting grid squares to a polygon?

Tags: analysis

I know I can generate a group of fixed sized intersecting square grids for a polygon using the bounding box of the polygon and generate gird squares on that and keep those, which are intersecting with the polygon. But this is not the best minimal fit of the grid squares. So is there any method to generate the minimum number of intersecting grid squares to a polygon?

Comment: This question (about creating a rotated grid inside a polygon) might give you some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/258912/81764

Comment: Probably, but with sufficient polygon complexity, it may be an [NP Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem.