# Rotation goes Wrong

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-modeler

I have a model that I built using model builder that creates a rectangle grid and then rotates it. For some reason, when I use rotate, it creates something wrong-

[image]

and it creates''holes'' between the rectangles-
[image]

When I use the model to create line grid and rotate it, it works well but is different .
[image]

How can I solve it?

**My end goal is to have rotated grid that will be made of polygons. I tried also to create polygons from the grid lines but it didn't work**

Comment: It looks like every single feature is rotated around its center. You could try to combine/union/collect/merge all features to one multipolygon (singlepart to multipart, etc.).

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258912/how-to-create-a-grid-inside-a-polygon-that-is-oriented-with-the-longest-side

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how did you rotate the polygon grid, but it seems you have used Rotate tool from Processing toolbox. If so, you need to specify the Rotation anchor [x,y], which enables you to select the rotation position directly from the map canvas, as you can see below:

Before rotation:

[image]

Using Rotate tool:

[image]

The Rotation anchor [x,y] was selected at the center of the intersection of the 4 polygons:

Final result:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the edit button to start editing, then select all polygons using the selection tool, and finally use the rotate tool [image] to rotate the polygons

[image]

But be careful, if you choose the alternative approach make sure to work on a copy of the polygon grid because once you save the edit it is irreversible.

Comment: But if I work with a model builder, I can't choose an anchor

Comment: @Reut You did not mention that you are using Model builder in your question. Please update your question, and write the method(s) that you are using.

Comment: it says on the first sentence that I have model

Comment: @Reut I have a model is different from I am using model builder to rotate polygons.

Comment: Does the rotation tool in the model builder allow you to set an expression-based anchor point? If so, an expression like this should work:  `centroid(collect($geometry))`