# Rotate polygons inside of a polygon to align with the longest side without manually adding a rotation angle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, alignment, rotate

Is there a way to rotate all polygons in layer_a (green polygons) to align with the longest side of the polygon in layer_b (red polygon) without having to manually enter a rotation angle? In most cases there would be multiple polygons in both layers - the idea would be for all polygons in layer_a to align with longest side of all the polygons in layer_b

[image]

[image]

I understand there is a similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258912/how-to-create-a-grid-inside-a-polygon-that-is-oriented-with-the-longest-side)

But the solution is tedious for the amount of polygons I'm planning to adjust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using QGIS 3.28, this can be achieved with the *Geometry by expression* tool.

```sql
with_variable(
    'current_rotation',
    main_angle($geometry),

    rotate( 
        $geometry,
        main_angle(
            overlay_intersects(
                'target poly',
                $geometry
            )[0]
        ) - @current_rotation       
    )
)
```

The rotation angle for each feature is found by using the `main_angle` function on the 'target polygon' that intersects with that feature. The `main_angle` of the original feature is subtracted from the rotation angle to deal with varying orientations.

From the help panel of the expression editor:

> **function main_angle**
>
> Returns the angle of the long axis (clockwise, in degrees from North) of the oriented minimal bounding rectangle, which completely covers the geometry.

I applied this expression on the red polygon layer. The black outlines are the 'target polygon' layer.

Result:

[image]

*Red polygons are the original geometry, blue polygons are rotated to the main axis of the polygon in 'target_poly' layer (black outline)*.